# How to convert Collection<object> to ArrayList< Dictionary<string, string> >?

Tags: c#

Hi I currently have a Collection container and I need to dump its contents into an ArrayList or a List. This ArrayList holds a dictionary object.

Now if I have something like this I tried doing ToList but it doesnt work

```
Collection<object> content = new Collection<object>();
....populate content container.....
List <Dictionary<string, string>> lst = new List <Dictionary<string, string>>();
lst= ( List< Dictionary<string, string> > ) content.ToList();
```

Any suggestions on how I could do this ?

Edit:
My content collection should be a list which contains a map.

Comment: Is the collection filled with Dictionary<string, string> only?

Comment: What kind of object is in the collection? How dou you want to get the strings out of it?

Comment: Yes the collection is filled with Dictionary<string, string>

Comment: When you say `ArrayList<>` you mean `List<>`, right? `ArrayList` isn't generic, so there is no such thing as `ArrayList<Dictionary<string, string>>`

Comment: @CodesInChaos I mean ArrayList da = new ArrayList();

Comment: You do not actually have to instantiate the list beforehand. ToList() returns a list already so whatever you instantiated would be lost anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it to Dictionary if you'd like, but you have to make sure you do the runtime checks...

```
lst = content.Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>().ToList();
```

Comment: Am i not suppose to mention the index value of the content first. The index value will tell which map to convert ?

Comment: Whoa whoa, what? Explain what you're trying to do clearly please because that changes this problem completely.

Comment: @AdamZedan the code I provided should work for this issue. Why do you have a collection<object> to begin with though? Why not just cast it to begin with?